# Use Rank() over a pseudo Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns:

- StudentName
- Marks1
- Marks2

from which I need to perform a query that will calculate the average of two marks and rank the rows from highest average to least.

I executed the following query:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT AVG(c) FROM (VALUES(Marks1),(Marks2)) T (c)) AS Average,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Average DESC) AS Position
from Marks;
```

But that gives an error:

> Average is an Invalid Column Name.

How do I fix this? How do I give a query to perform `Rank()` over `Average`.

Comment: Input and expected output?

Comment: Can't you just do `(Marks1 + Marks2) / 2` for the avg? Or you have many other columns or null values?

Comment: Yes, but my question is how do i rank the result by average?

Comment: Good point on the `NULL` values, @EzLo . Simply `/ 2` may not yield the correct result if the OP does have `NULL` values (one might hope that use `0` for someone than failed to attend but was still scored, and `NULL` for not applicable). Without sample data, or the OP telling us, we won't know which is correct.

Comment: Nice use of Shraddha Kapoor image for your profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference a column by its alias in the `SELECT`; the only place you can reference its alias is in the `ORDER BY` clause.

What you can do, however, is move the subquery to the `FROM`, and then you can reference the column returned in your (outer) `SELECT`:

```
SELECT M.*,--List your columns here, don't use *
       A.Average,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.Average DESC) AS Position
FROM Marks M
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT AVG(Mark) AS Average FROM (VALUES(Marks1),(Marks2)) V(Mark) ) A;
```

Comment: Thanks:).It worked. But How does Cross Apply works?.Is it similar to joins?

Comment: `APPLY` is similar to a `JOIN`, yes. Unlike with a `JOIN`, in `APPLY` you *can* reference objects outside of the scope, and it does not use an `ON` clause. It's most commonly seen when you reference Table-Value Functions.

Answer (score 3):

You should just use the average of the two marks inlined in the outer query:

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (Marks1 + Marks2) / 2 DESC) AS Position
FROM Marks
ORDER BY (Marks1 + Marks2) / 2 DESC;
```

Comment: This will work if marks doesn't have null values, just for the OP to know.

Comment: @EzLo Well if nulls be a concern, then the OP would need to first tell us how to handle `NULL` values.